# Read second checkbox value based on first check box selection in .jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, jqgrid

I have a `.jqGrid` where there is a hidden checkbox column created with value. To display a check box on UI, `multiselect: true` is used. So basically, I have a set of `<tr>` where one `<td>` is hidden which has some value.
I want to get the value of hidden `<td>` when displayed `<td>` is selected.

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gunjan_prmr/3wne3y5f/1/) link, I want to get the value of `2nd` checkbox (which is`"NDVoYzZ1aUNYdzAlM2Q1"`) and push it to an array when the user clicks on `1st`. If the user selects `1st` and `3rd` than array should have values of `2nd and 4th` checkbox.

How can I do that?

**HTML Snippet:**

```
 <tr role="row" id="0" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-highlight" aria-selected="true">
      <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;width: 20px;" aria-describedby="grid_cb">
        <input role="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="jqg_grid_0" class="cbox" name="jqg_grid_0"> 1st
      </td>
      <!-- HIDDEN TD  --> 
      <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="grid_check">
        <input type="checkbox" value="NDVoYzZ1aUNYdzAlM2Q1" name="Restaurants" id="Restaurants"> 2nd
      </td>
    </tr>
    </br>
    <tr role="row" id="1" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
      <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" aria-describedby="grid_cb">
        <input role="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="jqg_grid_1" class="cbox" name="jqg_grid_1"> 3rd
      </td>
      <!-- HIDDEN TD  --> 
      <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="grid_check">
        <input type="checkbox" value="QjBENlRFMW83SVElM2Q1" name="Restaurants" id="Restaurants"> 4th
      </td>
    </tr>
```

**.js Snippet:**

```
var res = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
  .each(function() {
    res.push($(this).eq(1).val());
  });

if (res.length == 0) {
  alert('You should select at least one option.');
  return;
}

alert("Values: " + res);
```

Comment: Your question is formulated only based on HTML fragments. It's difficult to understand what you try to implement. Do you want "pre-select" some rows of jqGrid during loading the data? Which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Which `datatype` has the grid? Working with JavaScript data (`data` of jqGrid) is much more quickly as working with DOM (like `value` of hidden chackboxs of hdden cells).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I do not want to `pre-select`. I want hidden `td` values to pass it on server side.  ` dataType` is 'json` and  `jqGrid` version is `4.4.0 (old one)`. `onSelectRow` and `onSelectAll` is used preserve user selected value.

Comment: First of all jqGrid 4.4.0 is more as 5 years old and it's dead since many years. It's strictly recommended to upgrade the jqGrid. Seconds, it's unclear how the strange information like `<input type="checkbox" value="NDVoYzZ1aUNYdzAlM2Q1" name="Restaurants" id="Restaurants"> 2nd` come in the hidden column. Your HTML fragment contains `id` duplicates (see `id="Restaurants"` in both columns). Do you use *custom formatter* or you get such data from the server? Could you post an example of **JavaScript code** which create the grid? In general you can use `getCell` or `getRowData` method to get data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly more then jqgrid you are looking for: how attach the click handler and how to get the second checkbox....

If it is so you can change this line:

```
res.push($(this).eq(1).val());
```

to:

```
res.push($(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input[type=checkbox]').val());
```

Remember, the IDs must be unique.

The snippet:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    var res = [];
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (idx, ele) {
        res.push($(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input[type=checkbox]').val());
    });

    if (res.length == 0) {
        console.log('You should select at least one option.');
        return;
    }

    console.log("Values: " + res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr role="row" id="0" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-highlight"
        aria-selected="true">
        <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;width: 20px;" aria-describedby="grid_cb">
            <input role="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="jqg_grid_0" class="cbox" name="jqg_grid_0"> 1st
        </td>
        <!-- HIDDEN TD  -->
        <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="grid_check">
            <input type="checkbox" value="NDVoYzZ1aUNYdzAlM2Q1" name="Restaurants" id="Restaurants1"> 2nd
        </td>
    </tr>
    </br>
    <tr role="row" id="1" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
        <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" aria-describedby="grid_cb">
            <input role="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="jqg_grid_1" class="cbox" name="jqg_grid_1"> 3rd
        </td>
        <!-- HIDDEN TD  -->
        <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;display:none;" title="" aria-describedby="grid_check">
            <input type="checkbox" value="QjBENlRFMW83SVElM2Q1" name="Restaurants" id="Restaurants2"> 4th
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Also, the ids created by `jqGrid` will be unique (i.e. `jqg_grid_0`, `jqg_grid_1` and so on).